# Jquery - One simple function to handle 16 different buttons being clicked?

Tags: jquery

I am creating an interactive colour sampler for a web site, which has 16 different swatches which can be clicked to show the fullsize preview.

Using jQuery I have a function `show_preview(swatch_id)` which does all the good visual stuff. However to call that function, I am currently stuck with repeating 16 similar handlers:

```
<div id="#swatch_clicker_1>
<div id="#swatch_clicker_2>


$("#swatch_clicker_1").click(function() 
{
    show_preview('1');
}   
$("#swatch_clicker_2").click(function() 
{
    show_preview('2');
}
...
```

I've been reading round the subject, including here on Stack Overflow and modified a little code from another answer. So If I were to do something like this, would it still run efficiently (if at-all!)?

```
<div class="swatch_clicker" id="#swatch_clicker_1>
<div class="swatch_clicker" id="#swatch_clicker_2>


$(".swatch_clicker").click(function(event)
{
    var clicker_id=event.target.id;
    show_preview(clicker_id);
}
```

Thanks,

Phil

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well you almost have it right.

Here's how I would do it:

```
<div class="swatch_clicker" data-preview-number="1"></div>
<div class="swatch_clicker" data-preview-number="2"></div>

<script>
    $(".swatch_clicker").click(function() {
        show_preview( $(this).data('preview-number') );
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I understand that the data- attribute was only formalised in html 5. Would this method cause problems with those people who have older browsers?

Comment: No, it will not cause problems. In fact, you don't even have to use the html5 spec for these. You could simply call those attributes "preview-number" and jQuery (although I do NOT think normal JS) would still be able to access it. But if you're very concerned about valid HTML, however, simshaun did make a mistake. Hyphens can only be used after the word 'data'. The rest should be done with underscores (and no CamelCasing!).

Answer (score 1):

Not quite, because `event.target.id` will be something like 'swatch_clicker_1'. This will work though:

```
$(".swatch_clicker").click(function()
{
    var arr = this.id.split('_'); //returns an array like ['swatch','clicker',1]
    show_preview(arr[arr.length - 1]); //the final item in the array is the number you want
}
```

Note that the use of `event.target` in this case is not necessary. `this` will give you that target.

Finally, you shouldn't be includeding the `#` in your html for the id.

Comment: Thanks for your help. How could I have let that '#' slip into my html?!

Answer (score 0):

That will run just as well, although you probably need to parse out the number from the ID.